# Obtain updated value from tableView cell with getter and setter

Tags: swift, realm, getter-setter, getter, setter

currently I have 2 VC that hold different data to show user

ParentVC (tableViewCell) got `UILabel` for `totalBalanceLabel`

ChildVC (tableViewCell) got `UILabel` for `amountLabel`

When user added a new data into ChildVC Cell, `amountLabel` will be exactly the amount the user keyed in. And ParentVC’s tableViewCell’s `totalBalanceLabel` will sum up and show the total amount of user keyed in in ChildVC.

I am thinking of using getter and setter make ParentVC’s totalBalanceLabel show the sum up amount in childVC. But to no idea how to perform it.

Comment: Don't use UI components to store data. Use model objects for that.

Comment: Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Noted with thank Gereon, never thought of that as still in the middle of learning. thanks alot!